# Highcharts export time stop navigating to demo page using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am using HighCharts version 6.0.1. Have set up the Highcharts with angularjs server locally for exporting the charts. When download as png/jpeg/pdf is selected from the top right corner of the chart , 
the Highcharts demo page is displayed and i am redirect to other link "https://export.highcharts.com/".

Please let me know what could be the reason for this.

i have add this 2 js link.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use offline-exporting.js instead of exporting.js

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
```

[Full exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/offline-download/)
i hope that help you

Comment: Thanks for your help and give a replay